# jsmserializer deserialize json child property

Tags: json, symfony, yaml, jmsserializerbundle

I am new in symfony/jmsserializer. A simple question: is it possible to deserialize a child property from json?

```
"rooms": [
        {
            "type_name": "Country-House-Room 27m",
            "max_child_occup": null,
            "uri": null,
            "code": "1",
            "quantity": 6,
            "max_occup": 2,
            "min_occup": 1,
            "types": [
                {
                    "bed_code": "3",
                    "type_code": null,
                    "quantity": null,
                    "type": "42",
                    "non_smoking": true,
                    "promo_code": null,
                    "size": 27,
                    "std_num_beds": 2,
                    "std_occup": 2,
                    "max_rollaways": 0
                }
            ],
```

I need to get the type property. I am work with yaml configuration. I have tested many syntax, but it sucks.

```
SAT\SeekdaBundle\Entity\RoomType:
exclusion_policy: ALL
properties:
    id:
        expose: true
        type: integer
        serialized_name: code
    seekdaId:
        expose: true
        type: integer
        serialized_name: code
    culture:
        expose: true
        type: string
        serialized_name: language
    title:
        expose: true
        type: string
        serialized_name: type_name
    maxOccupation:
        expose: true
        type: integer
        serialized_name: max_occup
    minOccupation:
        expose: true
        type: integer
        serialized_name: min_occup
    roomTypeType:
        expose: true
        type: integer
        serialized_name: types->type # here have i tested my magic syntax
```

Thanks Guys!

Comment: You can define specific group to types, and when you want to serialize only types use that group specification.

Comment: Thanks @MertÖksüz! I want the properties to deserialize from my json string...from the documentation ([link](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies)) can i not figured out, how i that have to implementing...as i sad: i am very new in symfony ;-)

Comment: Should you have any further ideas?

Comment: best and easiest way is the groups, of course there is other ways but harder than what i suggest. If you open the link what you wrote, you will se the `/** @Groups({"list", "details"}) */` you can define your own groups like that for types field.